# How to properly handle the landing part in a jump animation

Tags: animation, sprites

Look at this sprite sheet.

[image: Megaman]

It is clear that frame 1-3 are the "jump up" frames after which the last frame will be fixed until the "peak" of the jump (when gravity starts pulling back). When moving back down frame 4-7 are used and it all ends with an "idle" frame (which is not shown here in this jump sprite).

My question is about frame 6 and 7 in this sprite. When the entity "lands" after a jump it is suppose to run animation 6-7 as the "landing" animation. When moving down in a jump frame 4-5 are easy because they are the "start" of the animation. Frame 5 can be kept for as long as you fall... but what is the appropriate way to go from frame 5 to 6-7-x? Do you check if the frame after the next is a fall and then "initiate" landing or do you do that when you have actually hit the ground?

It can't be timed because of various scenarios such as jumping off a cliff or jumping under a low roof hitting your head and bouncing you back down.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I guess the usual approach is to have three jump-related states: *Jumping* (a hero rises to the highest point of jump), *Falling* (from the highest point of jump to the ground), *Landing* (jump ends with hero standing on the ground).

There are several ways of detecting these states, usually it's a several collision checks setting state flags. For example, in a character's physics step we may check for collisions below, and if there aren't any, then character is in the air. Now if a character has positive vertical speed, it's a *Jumping* state, otherwise it's a *Falling* state. If it's a *Falling* state, and we detected a collision below, than it's a *Landing* state, so lets switch to the landing animation.

This animation usually plays when hero has actually hit the ground. The animation sequence is short, so landing will look high-speed, also it  creates a feeling of crisp and precise controls. Sometimes character can do a long landing sequence, but then it's possible for a character to cancel landing animation and start running, e.g. Castlevania: SotN.

Comment: +1. Good point about states. From states you can figure out other details / modes.

Answer (score 5):

I've seen this done two ways:

1. When the bounding box first collides with the ground make a fast transition 5->6->7.
2. Have a second 'ghost' bounding box, that extends a small portion below the actual bounding box to initiate the 5->6, then upon the actual bounding box colliding do 6->7.

Comment: Liked the 2nd case. Seems very flexible because the ghost bounding box can be set far away depending on the speed of the character!

Comment: Interesting approach Nbr 2. I never ended up trying it but i will keep it in mind thank you.